# Rails routing - url helper results in 'undefined method'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

routes.rb

```
  match 'mybookings/:token' => 'mybookings#test', :as => 'bookit'
  resources :mybookings
```

rails routes shows:

```
bookit /app/mybookings/:token(.:format) mybookings#test
```

Then I use a helper:

```
=link_to "by clicking here", bookit_url(@client.token)
```

Which results in

```
ActionView::Template::Error
Error
undefined method `bookit_url' for #<#<Class:0x007fd2c1ca3488>:0x007fd2c1f96960>
```

What's wrong with that helper?

Comment: Can you show us the line for `bookit` in `routes.rb`?

Comment: Hmm, it’s a mystery to me. What happens if you try this in the console? `app.bookit_url(0)` Also, this isn’t what you asked and is getting more into design philosophy, but you might consider [adding more RESTful actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) instead of creating this custom route. Also also, haha, is there a reason you’re calling it `mybookings` and not just `bookings`?

Comment: In my experience, this can happen when there is more than one route that could match the route that the helper would produce.

Comment: Yes. Share the rest of `routes.rb`, @99miles?

Answer (score 1):

your code works fine for me in Rails 3.2

here are the key code:

```
# in routes.rb
match 'mybookings/:token' => 'mybookings#test', :as => 'bookit'

# in controller:
class MybookingsController
  def test
    render :text => 'this is bookit action'
  end
end

# in your erb or haml file:
link_to "by clicking here", bookit_url('this is the token string')
```

Comment: Thanks! It turns out the problem was simply that I was calling this from a mailer sent by Resque so I had to do this Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.bookit_url('12312')

Comment: I had an issue like this with AlchemyCMS. Answer from `99miles` works like a charm! But I don't like this strange behaviour with url_helpers.